# Deploy nodejs REST API on Amazon vps

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-ec2, vps, hapi.js

I have an account Amazon VPS.
I wanna deploy REST API on it.

But, I have a problem when trying to deploy.

[image]

It runs stable on localhost.

Could you please help or give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following configurations in this order:

- Use `ssh` to hop on the server and check if the Node process is up and running (e.g. `curl localhost:8080/api/users`)
- Ensure you're bound to all IP addresses (e.g. `0.0.0.0`) - check by running `curl ec2-hostname:8080/api/users` on the server
- Firewall port is open for `8080` inbound traffic using a security group